# Unfortunately (project name) has stopped working on button click

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

- An area which will present a predefined question
- A button which will cause the answer to the question to be shown while leaving the question on the screen
- An area which will present the answer
- A button which will cause a transition to a screen that is formatted the same as this one, with the next question shown on it
- A button which will cause the app to end (a transition to (3))

Only trying to get the transition from screen 1 to screen 2 to work with a different question/answer pair in its place with a button click.  If there is anyway to do this other than switching the screens and activities which is the error, please let me know.

```
package com.example.androidassignment2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Intent;

public class AndroidAssignment2 extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_android_assignment2_1);

        Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.QButton);
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.android_assignment2_1, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

layout file

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView android:id="@+id/Questions"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:text="@string/Q2"   />

<Button android:id="@+id/QButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_question"  />

<Button android:id="@+id/AButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/Answers"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:hint="@string/A2" />

<Button android:id="@+id/QuitButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_quit" />


</LinearLayout>
```

activity 1 file (incase needed)

```
package com.example.androidassignment2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.QButton);
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), AndroidAssignment2_1.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Please always post the logcat stack trace.  If you don't know how, ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), AndroidAssignment2_1.class);
startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
```

You are starting a new activity, the most likely cause is that this is has not been declared in the Manifest.

In your AndroidManifest.xml`, you will need to add something like this:

```
<activity
    android:name="your.package.name.AndroidAssignment2_1" />
```

This will reside inside of the `<application>` tag.

Comment: I had a dot in front of the first word in the package name.  >:|

Answer (score 0):

You are using `startActivityForResult()` but you don't override the `onActivityForResult()` method in your first `Activity`. You could change that to just use `startActivity()` and remove `setResult()` from your second `Activity`.

```
Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.QButton);
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), AndroidAssignment2_1.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
```

If this isn't your problem then please post logcat (always when you have a crash) and make sure the `Activity` is decalred.

As far as your other inquiry

> If there is anyway to do this other than switching the screens and activities which is the error, please let me know.

If you are simply changing the text then you can stay in the same `Activity` and change the text of your `TextView`s. You could store questions and answers in something like `Array`s or in a DB if you wish and keep a counter to where you are and change the text with each click.

Another option, which may go along with the first if you want, is to use a [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)